# Cache images/js/css never HTML content

Tags: php, image, caching, header

I'm looking for a PHP header() way to cache images but never html content of php output.
For now, I am using theses lines on my .htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|avi|mov|mp4|mpeg|mpg|mp3|pdf|doc|css|js|html|bmp|js|css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400000"
</filesMatch>
```

And I don't do any header.

I would prefer to send headers like these at the top of my php files, so I tried these:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But with these header functions, images are not cached in browsers if I close the browser and go back to the site.
Whhat do I have to send to browsers to cache images but never HTML content ?

**EDIT:**
Sorry but I checked again and I feel like these header functions are enough to make the browser cache images and not the html content.

Answer (score 0):

one option may be to load your images from a dedicated php file:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Cache-control: private');
$img = imagecreatefrompng("example.png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

to save having a separate php file for each, you could pass the filename on the uri.  eg, the path to the image would then be image.php?filename=example.png, using $_GET['filename'] in the php script.

*im not sure if Cache-control: private would really be necessary, but ive included it as hopefully helpful hint.

Comment: No I was speaking about image files not about php script files generating images.

Comment: i dont know if that would solve your problem anyway, to be honest.  im assuming youre talking about including the images in html markup within the php file, rather than viewing the images directly in the browser.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I was speaking about this: `echo "<img src=\"$img/myImage.png\" height=\"800\" width=\"300\">" ;` and want the browser to cache the file `http://www.mysite.com/images/myImage.png`. Actually the header functions I was talking in my question are working fines.